# Difficulty aggregating R POSIXlt list :Invalid type list error message

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate quarterly hour data but I am getting the error message  invalid type (list). The list is a POSIXlt list and I have aggregated minutely and hourly data before but I have never seen this error before. Do I need to convert the list to a different type and if so, would I still be able to extract the 15min data? Here is my code, I would really appreciate any help:

```
seq_start <- as.POSIXct("2015-09-10 01:00:00 BST")

Arrivals <- floor(runif(60, min = 1, max = 14))
Minute_Seq <- seq(trunc(seq_start, units='mins'), by='1 mins',length = 60) 
Arrival_board = data.frame(Minute_Seq,Arrivals)

Arrival_board$QTR= as.POSIXlt(round(as.double(Arrival_board$Minute_Seq)/(5*60))*(5*60),origin=(as.POSIXlt('1970-01-01')))
arrive_stats <- aggregate(Arrival_board$Arrivals ~ Arrival_board$QTR, Arrival_board, FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Could you post some sample of your data that replicates this error? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You want `as.POSIXct` where you use `as.POSIXlt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POSIXlt` is a list type, use `POSIXct` instead:

```
aggregate(Arrivals ~ QTR, transform(Arrival_board, QTR=as.POSIXct(QTR)), FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I knew that it would be a simple solution and I think I now finally understand the difference between POSIXct and POSIXlt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to binning your data via your QTR expression.  It uses the seq.Date and cut command.  It is more straight forward than divide round and multiple:

```
seq_start <- as.POSIXct("2015-09-10 01:00:00 BST")
Arrivals <- floor(runif(60, min = 1, max = 14))
Minute_Seq <- seq(trunc(seq_start, units='mins'), by='1 mins',length = 60) 
Arrival_board = data.frame(Minute_Seq,Arrivals)

QTR= seq(trunc(seq_start, units='mins'), by='5 mins',length = 13)
Arrival_board$QTR = cut(Arrival_board$Minute_Seq,QTR)

arrive_stats <- aggregate(Arrival_board$Arrivals ~ QTR, Arrival_board, FUN=mean)
```

Do to the differences on how the bins are defined there will be slight shift in the results.  To correct for this case with a 5 minute window, change the seq_start time by 2 minutes:

```
QTR= seq(trunc(seq_start-(2*60), units='mins'), by='5 mins',length = 14)
```